# Модернизация метода Replace() для строки

Tags: c#, циклы

есть строка с текстом вида "D15 D7 B12 String..." как привести к нормальному виду так что бы не прописывать миллион Replace();

```
Replace("D1", "1").Replace("D22", "22").Replace("String", "Новая Строка").Replace("Enter","С новой строки");
```

можно ли как то занести в массивы или перечисления все приходящие значения и все отредактированные а потом просто в цикле заменять первые на вторые?

Comment: можно....... но видимо вы городите какой-то костыль..... может скажите, что вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пользователь вводит в 1 текстбокс "TEXT" на что в соседнем появляется подсказка "строка текста" или "BEGIN" в 1 боксе а во 2м "Начало операции.." и тд.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сделать автоматический перевод текста, что ли?

Comment: @VladD Да, что то вроде словаря что бы пользователь видел краткое описание того оператора, который он ввел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое решение с использованием словаря отлично работает. Кому интересно что б не писать портянку из replace

```
        Dictionary<string, string> RusDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        RusDict.Add("command","новая команда ");
        RusDict.Add("delete","удалить");
        //==============//

      var value = string.Empty;
      foreach (var keys in RusDict.Keys)
      {
            RusDict.TryGetValue(keys, out value);
            if (RusDict.ContainsKey(textBox2.Text))
            {
                if (textBox2.Text == keys)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = value;
                }
              }
            }
        if (!RusDict.ContainsKey(_key))
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Нет значения в словаре";
        }
```

тему можно считать закрытой.

Answer (score 2):

Например, передавать коллекцию классов.

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Replace(this string str, IEnumerable<ReplaceItem> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            str = str.Replace(item.Old, item.New);

        return str;
    }
}

public class ReplaceItem
{
    public string Old { get; set; }
    public string New { get; set; }
}
```

Использование:

```
"asfasf".Replace(new[] { new ReplaceItem { Old = "old1", New = "new1" },
                         new ReplaceItem { Old = "old2", New = "new2" }});
```

Comment: Поскольку замен планируется много, возможно, имеет смысл использовать промежуточный `StringBuilder`? Он тоже умеет `Replace`.

Comment: @VladD да, ибо слишком много экземпляров в памяти будет.

Comment: Тогда может быть допишите в ответ?

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу @Vadim Prokopchuk, немного модифицированный вариант для уменьшения нагрузки на память.

```
static string ReplaceByDict(string s, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
        sb.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Обратите внимание, что этот вариант ведёт себя непредсказуемым образом, если среди ключей один является подстрокой другого, или если текст после замены содержит один из ключей.

Comment: Непредсказуем вариант @Vadim Prokopchuk или ваш ?

Comment: @Сергей: Оба. Будет ли заменено более длинное или боле короткое слово, зависит от случайных факторов. (Попробуйте, например, внести в словарь «кот» и «котик».)

Comment: я уже опробовал вариант со словарем и не вижу смысла передавать коллекцию классов.

Comment: @Сергей: Вот пример: http://ideone.com/qajr3d

Comment: @VladD можно ограничить пробелами с двух сторон, используя регулярные выражения. Но это не решит полностью проблему

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk: Это частично решит проблему, если заменяются всегда _полные_ слова. Но ещё есть проблема в случае, когда текст _замены_ содержит слово из текстов-ключей.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй посмотреть в сторону расширений и ключевого слова params. Что то вроде:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Replace(this String str, params string[] args)
    {
        string result = str;
        for(int i=0; i<args.Length-1; i+2){
            result = result.Replace(args[i], args[i+1]); 
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Обязательно сделай все необходимые проверки на четность и наличие аргументов.